# How to stub async module dependencies for jest

Tags: node.js, async-await, jestjs, sinon, stub

Let's say I have the following route:

```
import {example} from '../some/place'

const processRequest = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
      try {
        console.log('in route handler')
        const foo = await example(req.body.someData)
        res.status(200).send()
      } catch (e) {
        next(e)
      }
}
export { processRequest }
```

And then I write a test like so:

```
import * as exampleModule from '../some/place'
import { processRequest } from '../routes/processRequest'
import sinon from 'sinon'
sinon.stub(exampleModule, 'example').returns(new Promise(() => {
     return someData
})
describe('example test', () => {
    it('example test', async () => {
      await processRequest(mockRequest, mockResponse, mockNext)
    })
})
```

This fails with:

```
thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

Through console.logs, I have verified the following:

1. The original implementation of example *is not called*
2. ProcessRequest is called and prints to console
3. The line in the route after `const foo = await example(req.body.someData)` is never called and nothing is printed, suggesting that somehow the promise return from my stub is incorrect. For the life of me I do not know how.

Any advice on the best way to stub async dependencies for jest tests would be super welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An working example:

`processRequest.ts`:

```
import { NextFunction, Response, Request } from 'express';
import { example } from './someplace';

const processRequest = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    console.log('in route handler');
    const foo = await example(req.body.someData);
    console.log('foo: ', foo);
    res.status(200).send();
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
};
export { processRequest };
```

`someplace.ts`:

```
export const example = async (arg) => 'real data';
```

`processRequest.test.ts`:

```
import * as exampleModule from './someplace';
import { processRequest } from './processRequest';
import type { Response, Request } from 'express';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('example test', () => {
  it('example test', async () => {
    const exampleStub = sinon.stub(exampleModule, 'example').resolves('test data');
    const mockRequest = {
      body: { someData: 'a' },
    };
    const mockResponse = {
      status: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      send: sinon.stub(),
    };

    const mockNext = sinon.stub();
    await processRequest((mockRequest as unknown) as Request, (mockResponse as unknown) as Response, mockNext);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(exampleStub, 'a');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mockResponse.status, 200);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mockResponse.send);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/74944946/processRequest.test.ts (7.98 s)
  example test
    ✓ example test (16 ms)

  console.log
    in route handler

      at stackoverflow/74944946/processRequest.ts:6:13

  console.log
    foo:  test data

      at stackoverflow/74944946/processRequest.ts:8:13

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.442 s, estimated 9 s
```

package versions:

```json
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"sinon": "^15.0.1",
```